# Making a python UI - is Tkinter the best option?

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

I currently have a script that automates sending Whatsapp messages. It takes an excel file full of contacts, receives a message argument and then sends the message to each contact. It's purpose is to help automate sending the same message about different services being offered to a bunch of groups.

I am making the program for a family member who is computer illiterate and am hoping to make some simple UI for them so they never have to interact with the code.

I have already been playing around in tkinter, and have figured out how to open a dialog to select the Excel file that needs to be used. I am confused about how the rest of the program would functionally work and if this is feasible for someone who has never used Tkinter before and is on a short deadline.

I was thinking it would look something like a button, to open up the dialog to choose the Excel file. A text box, to fill in the message. And, another button to open up a dialog to choose a photo to be sent along the message. Then once all that was done the program would run.

Is this functionally possible, and is Tkinter the best option to pursue? Also is this feasible first project for a novice Tkinter user?

Answer (score 1):

Python is best for backend

---

Hey, so I think Python isn't the best language for UI at all.
In my opinion it is quite difficult to make a real good looking program with tkinter, but as I said before, Python is more for backend programming. But tkinter is not a bad choice for a simple program - if not the best. Also, the advantage of a tkinter program is that you can write your code and the GUI code in one file, which makes the program a bit more compact
But if you want a simple GUI program tkinter is you first choice